# Angular 13 app, wrapped in web component DI {providedIn: 'root'} issue

Tags: angular, web-component

I have a blank angular 13 application wrapped by a custom web component using `@angular/elements`. Here is the repo to the project

https://github.com/IanvanZyl636/Angular-13-web-component-issue

In this project, I have a lazy loaded `test.module.ts` with `test.service.ts` declared in its `providers` array. The `test.service.ts` is also `providedIn: 'root'`. I am trying to inject a token into the `test.service.ts` and change the token value within the lazy loaded `test.module.ts`.

**TOKEN:**

```
export const TESTERTOKEN = new InjectionToken<string>('TESTERASDASDAS');
```

**Change of value in `test.module.ts`:**

```
{
  provide:TESTERTOKEN,
  useValue:'a234234'
}
```

**Injection into `test.service.ts`:**

```
constructor(@Optional()@Inject(TESTERTOKEN) asd:string) {
  const pop = asd;
}
```

**The problem**

Here is a video visually explaining the issue:
https://youtu.be/1mXAPIEc5uU

When the app is wrapped with a custom web component, the `test.module.ts` value change fails.

When I remove the custom web component the value change works

When I remove the `providedIn: 'root'` from the `test.service.ts` the value change works.

**Solution I am after**

I want the app to be wrapped with web component and the service to stay `providedIn: 'root'` where the value change is working within the lazy loaded module `test.module.ts`.

Comment: This is an official bug with @angular/elements. There is a workaround read all about it here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37441